# Why do Blazor lifecycle methods execute out of order when there is an async method call?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Consider this terribly simple component:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitialized - Start");
        string result = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("sayHello"); // This could be any async method call, even "await Task.Yield();".
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitialized - End");
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnAfterRender - Start");
        Console.WriteLine("OnAfterRender - End");
    }
}
```

The result in the console is as follows:

[image]

As you can see, after the call to `JS.InvokeAsync` method inside of the `OnInitialized` method, Blazor suddenly jumps to the `OnAfterRender` method, executes it completely, and then comes back to the `OnInitialized` method and continues where it left off. And after that, it executes the `OnAfterRendered` method once again.

What is exactly going on here?! Shouldn't `OnAfterRender` be executed AFTER `OnInitialized`?!

Now, if I don't make an async call, and do something ordinary (in this example I have commented the JS interop call and I'm just defining 2 variables and swapping them), like this:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitialized - Start");
        //string result = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("sayHello");
        int a = 10;
        int b = 15;
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitialized - End");
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnAfterRender - Start");
        Console.WriteLine("OnAfterRender - End");
    }
}
```

This would be the result in the console:

[image]

As you can see, now the order is expected and normal. So, I'm sure there is something I don't know about Blazor's lifecycle methods, or how async operations affect them. I'm asking what that is. Thanks.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That's right. But I didn't claim otherwise. The second method (`OnAfterRender`) being async was merely a copy-pasting error. I removed it and made `OnAfterRender` a regular synchronous method. My question still stands, though. Because the results don't change.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That's right. I understand what's going on now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @enet I'm sorry why did you remove your answer?